# why there is a LoadStore instruction?

Tags: java, memory-barriers

I'm learning the JSR-133 cookbook from the page [JSR-133](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html), in the section 'Categories', the author gave an example about memory barriers.Below are the code:

[image: code]

I just do not understand why there is a 'LoadStore' between 'load u' and 'load b'. can anybody help me? thanks.

Comment: It isn't a instruction. `load` and `sfore` are the instructions here.

Answer (score 1):

> Why there is a 'LoadStore' between 'load u' and 'load b'?

It is actually a barrier required between 'load u' (Volatile Load) and 'store a' (Normal Store) at the end.

Comment: but there  is a 'load b'  between 'load u' and 'sotre a'. I think the memory barriers is insert between two adjacent instruction.

Comment: No, a memory barrier affects on **all instructions** of appropriate type before it and **all instructions** of appropriate type after it. And JVM requires a barrier to behave so. From the programmer's point of view, think about Java code (not byte-code) which involves adjacent volatile and normal variable's accesses. But when given code will be compiled and converted into the byte-code (low-level), the accesses to given variables could be no longer be adjacent. So, without "global" behavior of barriers they would be useless for programmer.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion matrix in the [JSR-133 cookbook for compiler writers](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html) seems to present an optimized view of the barriers necessary to implement `volatile` semantics.

The [semantics of `volatile`](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/j9mm.html) is essentially release/acquire with respect to non-volatile accesses + total order with respect to volatile accesses. Generally speaking, a load-acquire needs to emit `LoadLoad` + `LoadStore` barriers while a store-release needs to emit `LoadStore` + `StoreStore` barriers. To preserve total order for pairs of `volatile` accesses, a full fence can be emitted.

The `load u` followed by a `load b` and `store a` is a nice example of `volatile`sematics at work. Remember that `volatile` loads with respect to non-volatile accesses are essentially acquire semantics. That means that `load u` may not be reordered with any subsequent accesses, hence why both a `LoadLoad` barrier and `LoadStore` barrier are emitted. Without the `LoadStore`, `store a` could be reordered before `load u`, breaking the semantics of `volatile`.